# How do I calculate the total force required for a linear actuator?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-analysis, torque, linear-motion, linear-motors

[image]

How do I calculate the total forcerequired for a linear actuator?
The image enclosed shows a series of door panels, each with a cam that i would like to connect to a linear actuator on the right hand side.

In order to spec the actuator I need to estimate the total force, how do i go about doing this?

There will be 7No panels in series.
[image]

Comment: I think you need to improve your question a lot. It's not clear what the image has to do with your question. Stroke is how far you want the linear actuator to move. Force will depend on the friction, gravity, mass and required acceleration. You have given no details on any of these or anything else.

Comment: Please label the parts of the mechanism in the figure. Please use arrows to indicate the directions in which the movable parts can move. Please indicate the position and orientation of the actuator in relation to the mechanism.

Comment: @AJN Thanks both, sorry i am new to stack exchange. I have edited the image showing the directions. I am just after to formulas required to tally up the total loads so i can spec the actuator. There will be 7No cam's in series

Comment: Stroke needed is based on the angle to be moved and length of the lever.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks, are you able to help with the force?

Comment: The panels are operated in parallel. If they were in series the first would push the second which would push the third, ... Parallel is better because they'll all have pretty much the same play and will move together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sketch shows that the door panels are hinged balanced at the center.

This means they are at equilibrium in any position and can turn freely back and forth. And unless you need to flap them really fast, no angular momentum concerns.

All you need to deal with is the friction at the joints and links. And that depends on whether your system is put together well by correct bearings and connections or it's clunky and prone to jam.

Comment: Thanks @Kamran, So in theory If the friction is minimal, I can select one of the lowest force of actuators that suit the stroke?

Comment: @Daniel Hanson, yes, right.

Comment: @DanielHanson Using a spring scale it’s pretty easy to measure the force.